# vector<string> or vector< vector<char> >?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, boggle

I'm working on a [Boggle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle) game solver that would read lines of a text file (the board).

I've been going back and forth if I should use a `vector` of `string`s or a `vector` matrix of `char`s. I'm thinking the `vector` of `chars` would be easier to access as it would be `myvec[y][x]` where the `vector` of `string`s would require me to use the `string.at()` function.

I don't know which would have a better performance if I should parse each line in to the `char`s or leave the line as a `string` and access each `char` as needed. Any suggestions on which one I should do? Explaining *why* would be helpful.

Comment: You can use `[]` with strings too. `at` provides out-of-bounds checking.

Comment: @chris Oh never tried that with strings. Ok well that pretty much solved my question since a vector of strings will be easier. Thanks.

Comment: Strings are much better than char arrays. Always choose them if you can. Just so you know, the syntax is possible through the string class overloading `operator[]`.

Comment: @chris: While that is *generally* good advice, why would it be better for a Boggle game rather than a (essentially) a 2-d array of `char` where you're unlikely to be treating a row as a `string`?

Comment: @LF4: The best advice I can offer is to **start coding** with one or the other. If you have issues (performance, readability, maintainability, *etc*...) **then** switch.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, oops I missed the boggle part! Indeed a character array definitely works better for something like that. The question title is a bit misleading there. Strings should always be chosen if the sequence of characters has some meaning to it.

Comment: @chris: It looks like you were not the only one to read the title but miss the first sentence of the actual question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented, you can use `operator[]` on strings just like `vector`s or arrays.

Under proper optimisation, the performace will be about the same for `vector<char>` as for `string` - both are arrays under the hood, and in both cases `operator[]` will effectively be a structure member access and an indirect lookup.  They even provide almost the [same set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) of [methods](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Choose whichever makes your code more readable/simple.