# Convert a vector<vector<char>> into a vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, stl

I've got a

`std::vector<std::vector<char>>` and want to fill a `std::vector<string>` with its content.

I just can't get my head into thinking how to access the inner vector of and put the chars into a string vector.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think a `std::vector<char>` is like a string.
So it should not be hard to do and I'm just stuck somewhere in my mind.

I've seen this:
[vector<string> or vector< vector<char> >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491445/vectorstring-or-vector-vectorchar) but it didn't got me far.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The naive solution should work well enough:

```
std::vector<std::string>
chars_to_string(std::vector<std::vector<char>> const & in)
{
    std::vector<std::string> out;
    out.reserve(in.size());
    for (auto const & v : in)
        out.emplace_back(v.begin(), v.end());
    return out;
}
```

Comment: For the naive solution, I would not even bother with `resize`; amortized constant back insertion and all that.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an `algorithm` version

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> a;
std::vector<std::string> b;

std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b),
[](std::vector<char> const& v) -> std::string {
  return {v.begin(), v.end()};
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
std::vector<string> vec;
for(std::vector<std::vector<char>>::iterator itr = source.begin(); 
    itr != source.end(); ++itr) {
    vec.push_back(std::string(itr.begin(),itr.end()));
);
```

Comment: Since you are using C++11, I would advise: `for (auto const& e: source)` it's so much more readable. Also note that repeatedly computing `source.end()` at each iteration of the loop is not particularly "nice".

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do:

```
std::vector<char> v_char;
std::string my_string(v_char.begin(), v_char.end());
```

or also (requires C++11 and the vector of char must be NULL terminated):

```
std::string my_string(v_char.data());
```

Once you have the `std::string`, filling a vector is easy.

Comment: The first is definitely the way to go; it's also extremely efficient since the `std::string` can compute the expected length in O(1) as the difference between the two iterators and thus pre-reserve memory once and for all.